# Error when displaying a sfGuardUser

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I want to display member informations in a page.

Here is my `routing.yml`

```
member_show:
  url:   /membres/profil/:id
  class: sfDoctrineRoute
  options: { model: sfGuardUser, type: object }
  param: { module: member, action: show }
```

Here is my `actions.class.php`

```
public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  if($this->getUser()->isAuthenticated())
  {
    $this->member = $this->getRoute()->getObject();
  }
  else
  {
    $this->redirect('@homepage');
  }
}
```

But I get this error :

> Unknown record property / related component "user" on "sfGuardUser"

Here is the stack trace :

http://pastebin.com/G1rcLL6r

Comment: There is no any reference to `user` in the posted code. I think the problem is somewhere else, maybe in the template. You can see in the stack trace where the problem comes from.

Comment: Could you paste your template (`showSuccess.php`)?

Comment: <xxx id="xxxx" class="xxx">
  <xx><?php echo $member->getUsername(); ?></xx>
  <p>xxx</p>
</xxx>

Comment: as @1ed said, could you paste the whole stack trace? Every information inside will lead you to the problem

Comment: Had it in my question as a pastebin link. Can't paste it in my answer.

Comment: It's not a stack trace but a log. You can see how a stack trace looks like in [Figure 16-1](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/16-Application-Management-Tools). It's a snapshot of the state of your program when the failure occured. When you click on the dots (...) you can where the execution was in that file. Search the marked line in `showSuccess.php`, that's where the problem comes from. Probably it's a call something like this `->getUser()`. I think you trying to get a user from an object which is already a user.

Comment: Here it is : http://pastebin.com/4GnTnQce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace you posted as comment, you should write `$this->getResponse()->setTitle('XX - '.$this->member->getUsername());` at line #59 in `apps/frontend/modules/member/actions/actions.class.php`

Comment: @Elwyn stack trace always tolds you from where the problem come from. 90% of problem can be solve by carefully reading the stack trace :)